# Splitting code with innerHTML split but problem

Tags: split, innerhtml

```
"request": {
   "useSsl": true,
   "consistencyTokenJars": [{
       "encryptedTokenJarContents": "AGDxDeRl_RNxmbsvLAFzlza8LBiCJqXkDlZJp1tUJIGpuF3Lf30BFalK_07mxntlZRQaOzm0hUzf6q6UzbV2a33Etw-86ybZMwKxGeokOiftGgxcZ0vIhC0AXx3"
   }]
},
```

How can I split this part?

```
document.head.innerHTML.split('encryptedTokenJarContents":"')[1].split('"')[0];
```

I can't smash that part like this?

Comment: Could you write what your expectation is after splitting?

Comment: AGDxDeRl_RNxmbsvLAFzlza8LBiCJqXkDlZJp1tUJIGpuF3Lf30BFalK_07mxntlZRQaOzm0hUzf6q6UzbV2a33Etw

I want this part

Comment: What does that JSON structure have to do with `document.head.innerHTML`?  If what you have is a JavaScript object, can't you just reference the value directly?  Perhaps you could demonstrate the problem with a more complete runnable example?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCkY03dXdfgki8B9b7zbvYWA

subscribe to this channel first and then open the source code (CTRL + U) encryptedTokenJarContents Search for this

Comment: @Mohammed: *"subscribe to this channel"* - Stack Overflow is not a place to recruit YouTube subscribers/followers.  If you have information about the question, please include it in the question.  For tips and information on how to ask, you are encouraged to read [ask] and its linked resources.

Comment: I don't collect followers, I said it so that you can see that part in the source code without subscribing to the channel.

Comment: @Mohammed: Either way, information about the problem needs to be included in the question.  A link to YouTube isn't really useful here.

Answer (score 0):

it would be better to split string by

```
split("\"")
```

and then take 3rd element.

```
 var str= 'encryptedTokenJarContents": "AGDxDeRl_RNxmbsvLAFzlza8LBiCJqXkDlZJp1tUJIGpuF3Lf30BFalK_07mxntlZRQaOzm0hUzf6q6UzbV2a33Etw-86ybZMwKxGeokOiftGgxcZ0vIhC0AXx3'
console.log(str.split('"')[2])
```

Comment: can you send me the exact

Comment: Check the answer.

Comment: How do I pull it from the source?

https://prnt.sc/1197kdb